# when I use history.push url changes but doesn't render the component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I've seen problems like this but neither of them solved my problem.

I have a p tag that onClick is supposed to render a page.
But when I click on it and use this.props.history.push(/posts/${id}) It changes the url but doesn't render the component I want.

I have tried using a

```
onClick={(e, id) => this.postPage(e, post.id)}
```

to trigger a function that will trigger the component I want to show up. I also tried using

```
<Link to-=''>
```

insted of

```
<p onClick>
```

but it doesn't work either.

This is what I have done so far, this is the function that triggers when I click the p tag:

```
 postPage = (e, id) => {
    const { history } = this.props;
    history.push(`/post/${id.toString()}`);
  }
```

and also, I used withRouter to have access to the history prop.

```
 export default withRouter(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Post));
```

And these are the routes I mapped:

```
  render() {
     return (
       <div className="Routes">
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home}></Route>
            <Route path='/post/:id' render={(history) => (
               <PostPage {...history}></PostPage>
            )}></Route>
          </Switch>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And of course, when I call this component I also pass using BrowserRouter

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I just wanted to render the  component but only the URL changes and nothing happens.

Comment: is the home page component still visible after the url changes?

Comment: And you should remove the closing tags for the routes: `<Route exact path='/' component={Home} />` instead of `<Route exact path='/' component={Home}></Route>`.

Comment: yes. The home page is still visible. Actually nothing happens. Already removed the closing tags, still doesnt work

Comment: if you replace the PostPage route with a regular route, and use `<Link to="some-link" />` does it work?

Comment: No. I tried rendering another component and it also doesn't work

Comment: Interesting. If you can recreate at codesandbox.io I can take a look.. can't see any other issues with your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186202/discussion-between-jeff-goes-and-toby).

Answer (score -1):

A good approach would be to implement react-redux and react-router-dom one at a time, to ensure that there are no clashes. The double HOC here:

```
export default withRouter(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Post));
```

Is worth breaking down to:

```
export default withRouter(Post);
```

To ensure that react-router-dom works as expected, then implementing react-redux once routing is in place.

Answer (score -1):

For those who have had the same problem the solution was to change the BrowserRouter tag location from the index.js to inside of the component that uses the Route. I was doing something like:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Provider>
<BrowserRouter>
<App>
</BrowserRouter>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and now inside the Routes.js component

```
render() {
<BrowserRouter>
<Route ...>
<Route ...>
</BrowserRouter>

}
```